# Q: Properties of a given conditional probability density

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve the following question:

> Let $X\sim exp(1)$. Define $Y$ such that given $X=x$, $Y$ distributes uniformly in the interval $[x,x+1]$
>
> - Find the density $f_{Y}(y)$.
> - Find $E(Y)$.
> - Suppose now that $X\sim exp(2)$. Find $E(Y)$.

My try:

$$f_{Y}(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{Y\mid X=x}(y)\; f_X(x)\operatorname d x \\ =\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{x+1-x}\;\mathbf 1_{[x,x+1]}\; e^{-x}\operatorname d x \\ =\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathbf 1_{[x,x+1]}\; e^{-x}\operatorname d x$$

Now I'm not sure. does the last integral equals $\int_{y}^\infty e^{-x}\operatorname d x$ or $\int_{y}^{y+1} e^{-x}\operatorname d x$ ?

As for the second part:

$$E(Y)=E(E(Y|X))=E(\frac{2x+1}{2})=E(X)+\frac12=\frac32$$

As for the third part, is it conceptually different in some way from part two, or should I simply plug in the relevant expected value ($E(X)=\frac12$) into $E(Y)=E(X)+\frac12$ ? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The first part is a little bit subtle. First you did well by trying to find out the joint pdf of $(X, Y)$:

$$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{Y|X=x}(y|x)f_X(x) = e^{-x}, 0 < x < +\infty, x < y < x+1$$

Special care is needed with this support as it is not rectangular. When you want to integrate out $x$ first to obtain the marginal pdf of $Y$, you need to found the "tightest" bound (i.e. not $(0, +\infty)$) given by other variables. Note
$$ x < y < x+1 \iff y - 1 < x < y$$
Incorporating with the bound $ 0 < x < +\infty $, the support can be also stated as
$$ 0 < y < +\infty, \max\{y-1, 0\} < x < y$$
You can always try to draw it on the $x-y$ plane to help you understand the shape of the support, but it is difficult if you are dealing with 3 or more variables. Eventually we have
$$ f_Y(y) = \int_{\max\{y-1, 0\}}^{y} e^{-x}dx, 0 < y < +\infty$$
which should gives a piecewise function.

2) Yes just substitute it for the third part.